# Is any possible that post to groups with Open Graph API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Since /PROFILE_ID/feed will be not supported(refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/)), is any possible to post message to user's groups with OpenGraph API?
Thanks.

Comment: Posting to groups isn't affected by the February 2012 migration

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to post message to user's groups with OpenGraph API? YES

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed